# REPLACE TEXT in SSRS (based on Parameter)

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

just a quick question, i have an issue with SSRS, i have 2 parameters, lets say 'parameter_1' and 'parameter_2' i need to change a text in text box (company name 1 and 2) if one of them (parameter) is on,

=IIf(Parameters!FilterParameter.Value="parameter_1" then "company_name1")

=IIf(Parameters!FilterParameter.Value="parameter_2" then "company_name2")

cant figure out with syntax, please assist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is not very clear. You say you have 2 parameters, but it sounds like you have 1 parameter with 2 available values.

If that is correct and you simply want to return a different value depending on which is selected then you could do something simple like

```
=SWITCH(
        Parameters!FilterParameter.Value="parameter_1", "Company_Name_1",
        Parameters!FilterParameter.Value="parameter_2", "Company_Name_2",
        True, "Unknown company"
        )
```

alternatively, why not just set the parameter label to the company name you want, then you can just use

```
=Parameters!FilterParameter.Label
```

If I have misunderstood then please clarify your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick response. The first solution that you provided looks great, but still does not change the text in textbox, I cant set up a label for companies because these companies are not in SQL data, just text information i cant take a data from query, sql part and report part working witno issues, just braking up my head with simply question to changing text based on parameter( and yes, I apologize for my  question, there is just one parameter with 2 companies name in there ) Thanks again

Comment: It's midnight here but I will follow up tomorrow. Please edit your question to show what you get now and what you expect to see based on your parameter selection. Also show the current expression in the textbox, which I am assuming is where you want to add the expression I gave above?

Comment: Also show how you set up your parameter values, it still sounds like you could just use the parameter's label to do what you want.

Comment: i figured out with the issue above with your suggesting(thanks a lot), but faced with a new one , im sending an example below, if possible, please explain why it doenst work properly, report shows an error that cannot run this ;

Comment: You need to start a new question and if my answer helped, please mark the answer as accepted (the check mark to the left of the answer, under the vote up/down buttons)